# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “CREATE”

Tags: plsql

---

its showing error in 27 line create or replace function Buffalo

```
    Declare

    random_number number(4);

    user_number number(4);

    cow number(1);

    buffaloes number(1):=0;

    begin

    random_number:=uniquetest(random_number);

    /*random_number:=dbms_random.value(1000,9999);*/

    dbms_output.put_line(random_number);

    user_number:=&user_number;


    while(user_number!=random_number)

    loop

    buffaloes:=Buffalo(user_number,random_number);

    dbms_output.put_line('0'||'c'||buffaloes||'B');

    buffaloes:=0;

    user_number:=0;
    user_number:=&user_number;

    end loop;
    end;

    /*error in this line */
    create or replace function Buffalo
    (user_number in number,random_number in number)

    return  number 
    is

    user_comparision number(1);

    random_comparision number(1);

    buffaloes number(1);

    user_number1 number(4):=user_number;

    random_number1 number(4):=random_number;

    begin

    while(user_number!=random_number)

    loop



    user_comparision:=user_number1 mod 10;

    random_comparision:=random_number1 mod 10;

    user_number1:=user_number1/10;

    random_number1:=random_number1/10;

    if(user_comparision = random_comparision)
    then

    buffaloes:=buffaloes+1;

    end if;

    end loop;

    return buffaloes;

    end;/
```

---

it is showing error in create statement. can anybody help me in solving this error.

Tell how to solve this create statement error.

it is showing error in create statement. can anybody help me in solving this error.

Tell how to solve this create statement error.

Answer (score 0):

You should make 2 scripts of it. Currently you're starting off with a anonymous block, that is actually calling the function buffalo, while it hasn't been created yet.

Both the anonymous block and the function seem to be creating some infinite loop by the way, 
So I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here..
Without knowing the background of this problem it's impossible to give a solution.